# Update Signifyd Module via composer from 4.3 to 5.2

Tags: signifyd

I want to update Signifyd Module from 4.3 to 5.2 version. How to update module signifyd/module-connect?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I implemented.

```
composer require signifyd/module-connect ^5.0.0 --update-with-dependencies
```

It will upgrade the Signifyd to 5.2 (Latest) version, with dependencies.

Thanks.